# Push data from adls to dedicated sql pool with pyspark

Tags: azure, pyspark, azure-data-factory

I've source table in my ADLS and Target table in dedicated sql pool, and now I want to push the data from ADLS to dedicated sql pool with Pyspark

Answer (score 0):

Configure Access from Databricks to ADLS Gen 2 for Dataframe APIs.

Configure the OAuth2.0 account credentials in the Databricks notebook session.

To Read data from the ADLS Gen 2 datasource location into a Spark Dataframe.

```
source_path="abfss://url/sampledir/sampledata.csv"
df = spark.read.format("csv").options(header=True, inferschema=True).load(source_path)
```

For more information follow this [article](https://chinnychukwudozie.com/2020/11/13/write-data-from-azure-databricks-to-azure-synapse-analyticsformerly-sql-dw-using-adls-gen-2/) by jbernec